# segmentation fault even though memory is allocated

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

In this program I am trying to add onto the fields of a struct the values of lines of a file. But I encounter a problem :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct StudentRecord{
    long sid;
    char email[30];
    char lname[20];
    char fname[20];
    float cgpa;
    struct StudentRecord *next;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *file2 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   
    char line[200];
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    fgets(line, 200, file2);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    struct StudentRecord * head = NULL;
    while(fgets(line, 200, file2)){
         struct StudentRecord *recordStruct = (struct StudentRecord *) malloc(sizeof(struct StudentRecord));
         char *tok = strtok(line, ",");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
         sscanf(tok, "%ld", &recordStruct->sid);                                                                                                                                                                            
         tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
         strcpy(recordStruct->email, tok);
         tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    fclose(file2);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code returns `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

The `gdb` returns

[image]

Therefore I suspect, since strcpy tries to access `recordStruct`, that my `recordStruct` struct was not correctly allocated memory. But I have went over my code at least a dozen times, I feel like my syntax is okay. Does anyone have any clue of what possibly is happening?

I have explicitly called

```
struct StudentRecord *recordStruct = (struct StudentRecord *) malloc(sizeof(struct StudentRecord));
```

so why would then `strcpy(recordStruct->email, tok);` return a segmentation fault ?

Comment: You have an extra call to `fgets` before the loop, and you're not checking the return value of `strtok`.

Comment: You are basically ignoring the return value of all the functions you use. That's not going to end up well. Check what `fopen`, `fgets`, `strtok`, `sscanf` and `malloc` return and act accordingly.

Comment: The first `fgets` before the loop is to bypass the first line of the file. And sorry but what do you precisely mean by your second statement?

Comment: The `strtok` function could return NULL.  You need to check for that.

Comment: Allright thanks to you people !

Comment: In particular, if the `fgets` call reads a line that does not contain any commas (perhaps the last line in the file, for example) then it will return a truthy value, and the first `strtok()` call will return a valid pointer, but the *second* `strtok()` call will return a null pointer.  You might catch at least some such cases even before the second `strtok`, however, by checking the return value of `sscanf()` (should be 1 if it successfully scans and converts a number).